# Unable to find/alter default configuration for log4j when using JBossWS on client-side web services

Tags: java, log4j, jbossws

I created a web service client using JBossWS and am now having problems with logging. There seems to be some kind of default logging configuration being used (it is ignoring my log4j.properties file entirely), but I can't find where it is getting the information from.

Is there a way to find the location configuration data?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked:

`jboss-dir/server/{instance}/conf/jboss-log4j.xml`

?

Comment: I did, but all the threshold settings are correct. Right now my logger only creates a log file when the logging level is Fatal even when I have it set in the log4j.properties to be Debug. 

Something I forgot to mention in my original post is that I'm only using JBoss .jar files and not the application server, don't know if this is relevant or not.

Comment: It is, indeed. If you are using just JBoss jar, you've got no JBoss-dir/server/{instance}.

The logger depends on which application server you are using. Which one is it?

Comment: well, the logger is for the client-side, hence the jbossws is being used as a standalone, there will be no application server. The client will be using jbossWS-native-3.2.2 GA. http://www.jboss.org/jbossws/downloads/  
Also is there a way to force it to change where it retrieves the logging config?

Comment: It's ok now. I switched to java.util.logging instead of log4j which worked for me. Thanks for the reply Volothamp!